# Why can't a std::vector take a local type?

Tags: c++, vector, local-class

```
void foo() {
  struct Foo { .. };
  std::vector<Foo> vec; // why is this illegal?
}
```

I'm not returning Foo to the outside world. It's just a temporary type that I use within the function.

Comment: +1 Good question! Have never heard of that =)

Comment: @anon: May I know what compiler you used?

Comment: @anon: I could compile it in Visual C++ 2005 though, but I guess this doesn't follow the standard if it's really mentioned there.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A local class can't be a template argument. Because the standard says:-

14.3.1 paragraph 2:
"A local type, a type with no linkage, an unnamed type or a type
compounded from any of these types shall not be used as a
template argument for a template type parameter."

```
[Example:
template <class T> class X { /* ... */ };
void f()
{
struct S { /* ... */ };
X<S> x3; // error: local type used as templateargument
X<S*> x4; // error: pointer to local type used as templateargument
}
-end example] [Note: a template type argument may be an incomplete
type (3.9). ]"
```

One workaround is suggested [here](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.c++.moderated/msg/190eed7804da6a46?q=AnyUnaryFunction+author:olczyk%40interaccess.com&hl=en&rnum=2) on c.l.c++.moderated.

**UPDATE**:
There was some discussion on why is it not possible to have local-classes as template arguments? The links [here](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.std.c++/browse_thread/thread/eb135c68c293cd34/5c9c2e17f5518621?lnk=gst&q=template+local+classes#5c9c2e17f5518621) and [here](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.std.c++/browse_thread/thread/e869f0e552c376ed/23c9f2c2d85ade27?lnk=gst&q=template+local+classes#23c9f2c2d85ade27) on c.std.c++ discuss the same.

Answer (score 3):

*Short answer:*
Because the C++ standard says so (section `14.3.1`)

*Long answer:*
At the time that C++ was standardized, the C++ standards committee believed that there would be implementation and performance issues. Those fears turned out to be unfounded and, as of the final draft of the C++0x standard, they've reversed the decision.

---

On a more practical note, some compilers already support the new C++0x rules:

- **For MacOSX you'll need gcc >=4.5 with the `-std=c++0x` command-line parameter**
- For the Microsoft compiler you'll need >=vc8/VS2005 *without* the `/Za` option (disable language extensions)